# How to write a Keras Layer for basic vector/tensor multiplication

Tags: python, lambda, keras, matrix-multiplication

So I want to multiply the outputs of an embedding by a constant vector. I'm using the functional API rather than Sequential.

```
word_seq = Input(shape = (SEQ_LEN,), dtype = "int32", name = "word_seq") 

word_embs = Embedding(output_dim = EMBED_DIM, input_dim = VOCAB_SIZE, input_length = SEQ_LEN)(word_seq)
```

If I understand this correctly, because I haven't given a batch shape, `word_embs` should have shape (`None, SEQ_LEN, EMBED_DIM`).

I have a constant vector `(numpy array)` `q` of shape (`SEQ_LEN`,). So the matrix multiplication I want to perform is `q^T*`(the `seq_len` by embed_dim matrix inside `word_embs`).

I think I'll need to use the keras Variable to turn q into a tensor, but then a Dot layer or keras.backend.dot are both giving me trouble because of that None dimension on word_embeds. I don't want to use Flatten because that will reduce it to a single dimension, rather than just getting rid of the troublesome one. Is Reshape what I need then? Or can I pass word_embs[:] to the lambda layer or something?

Maybe I just don't know enough about tensors, but this is extremely frustrating. It seems like such an advanced python library should easily be able to do high school matrix multiplication but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 1 as the batch dimension for the constant tensor in your Lambda:

```
import keras.backend as K
[...]

def my_lambda(x):
    q_array = np.zeros((1, SEQ_LEN))
    q_array = ... # your value
    q = K.constant(q_array.T)
    return Dot()([q, x])

result = Lambda(my_lambda)(word_embs)
```

Comment: Okay thanks. But what if q isn't constant? It seems like Keras wants both matrices to have exactly the same dimensions for Dot() to work. Is that not the case? Is there an easy to way to understand which axis I want to use? Maybe that's the part I'm getting wrong